# SQL server 2008 installation error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, installation, sql-server-express

I had installed trial version of SQL 2008 R2 on my machine with win 7 as OS. Today I uninstalled it since trial expired then I tried to install SQL 2008 express edition with Advanced services but I keep getting below error:

[image: SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error Method not found Boolean Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.MsiExtensionMetadata.get_IsSlipstreamOrPatch()]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *manually* and completely un-install SQL Server first, as [per this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967)

Comment: I also blogged about my frustrations with this. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition.aspx

Comment: @Aron nice blog post.